# Inflation pool ledger protocol

Tags: security, ledger-nano, stellar-laboratory

When signing up for an inflation pool the hash on my Ledger and what was being displayed on the Stellar Laboratory did not match. I know that I am signing with my Ledger but is there any way for anyone to code something that forces the Ledger to give up its key to perform an action / transaction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the start of the hash displayed by the ledger is the same of the one displayed on laboratory, then is just a visualization bug

You can check [here](https://github.com/lenondupe/ledger-app-stellar/issues/9)

Just to be safe, after you sign a transaction, the signed xdr is shown on laboratory so you can review it before to post it on horizon

This way, using the laboratory, even if you sign an “injected transaction”, you will always able to “not submit” it